# couchdb read response conversion taking so much time

Tags: java, performance, couchdb

As per Company requirements, we need to fetch records from the CouchDB to show some reports.
For this, I developed a spring boot application that will interact with CouchDB with feignclient.

Here is my Controller Code:

```java
    @PostMapping("/query")
    private JsonNode getJsonData(@RequestBody JsonNode request) {

        QuerySelectorResponseModel respone = this.couchFeign.getExistingRecordByQuerySelector(
                "pr$6fdf4829-7172-481d-97fa-54ad3599037e", request);

        return respone.getDocs();
    }
```

And here is my Query Selector for Fetching Data :

```json
{
    "selector": {
        "KeyRegister": "99b1c98d-aac0-4e98-b7d1-922f5cba94f1",
        "attributes.basicStartDate": {
            "$gte": "20210801"
        },
        "attributes.basicFinishDate": {
            "$lte": "20210930"
        }
    },
    "limit": 2000
}
```

Request Response captured in the Image, open the Image.
[Execution Logs captured in the Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57txx.png)

Observations:

Feign Http Response given in 626ms but while converting data into model its taking more than 4 seconds.
Can anyone help me, How to Reduce Couchdb response assigning java model with less time

Comment: Always consult [explain endpoints](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html?highlight=explain#db-explain) when encountering a performance problem.  In essence, what index is that query using?

Comment: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html

Comment: built-in _all_docs index

Comment: Well there it is, your query is basically performing a full scan of the primary index with likely not a small amount of in memory processing.  It's the query that's time consuming, not reading the results. This calls for [creating an index](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html?highlight=create%20index#api-db-find-index) on the `basicStartDate` and `basicFinishDate` fields.

Comment: I am not worrying about couch response time, more worried about converting response to Java Model taking 4 secs for 2000 records